# QTimeEdit set max value greater than 23:59:59

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there any way to increase the `maxValue` of `QTimeEdit` to for example 26:00:00?

I would like to use it to a duration fied in my application.

Comment: is ``setMaxValue`` doable?

Comment: I believe it only accepts 23:59:59 as max parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation:

- When setting this property, the minimumTime is adjusted if necessary to ensure that the range remains valid. If the time is not a valid QTime object, this function does nothing. (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html#maximumTime-prop)
- The time is valid if h is in the range 0 to 23, m and s are in the range 0 to 59, and ms is in the range 0 to 999. (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#isValid-2)

So it is not possible.